# What is DCB in "Communications Structures"?

Tags: c#, serial-port

What does `DCB` stand for in **Communications Structures**? Is it a text file reside somewhere in the reference? What is the difference in the baud rate in `DCB` and the baud rate in `SerialPort` Class? When I'm using a `SerialPort` class am I also using `DCB`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DCB = Data or Device Control Block

It is not a text file. It is typically a `struct`. MSDN lists more information on [DCB at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). At CodeProject, there is a good introduction to S[erial Port Communications using the Win32 DCB Structure](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/SerialCommunication_DCB.aspx?display=Print). The SerialPort object/class is a wrapper. Baud Rates will be the same because the device will require a consistent baud rate.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply a structure that contains the serial port configuration.  Baudrate, handshaking etcetera.  You need it when you write native code, SetCommState() requires it.  Yes, you still use it when you use the SerialPort class.  It however hides it from view and gives you friendly properties.  Like BaudRate, Handshake, etcetera.  It uses the property values to create a DCB and pinvoke SetCommState when you call the Open() method.